# Can I call sql objects within multiple methods in nested loops

Tags: java, sql

I have a condition like below , I need to fill the dto's layer to create a structured xml.Is it the right way to pass preparedstatment and result set object in each calling method.
Or should I create a new preparedstatment and resultset object in each method.

```
 PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public List getList1()
    {
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("query1");
      resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

      if(resultSet != null & resultSet.getRow() > 0){
      SubsectionsDTO subsections = new SubsectionsDTO();
      SectionDTO sectionDTO = new SectionDTO();
      sectionDTO.setId("");
      sectionDTO.setSubsections(getList2(pstmt ,resultSet));
      } 
    }

    public List getList2()
    {
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("query2");
      resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

      if(resultSet != null & resultSet.getRow() > 0){
      SubsectionsDTO subsections = new SubsectionsDTO();
      SectionDTO sectionDTO = new SectionDTO();
      sectionDTO.setId("");
      sectionDTO.setSubsections(getList3(pstmt ,resultSet));
      } 
    }
```

Comment: It seems you are executing two different queries in two methods, right? Then this approach will throw exceptions, you may quickly verify by moving method2 code to end of method1.

Comment: i want to keep the code clean and readable. Hence I have separate method. What could be the possible error by the above approach. My database is not yet loaded with data. Hence Im just coding, cannot test.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is almost right. You should create a separate `PreparedStatement` with its respective `ResultSet` per SQL query.

Flaws I see in your design:

- The `Connection con` is declared as a field in your class. It is better to maintain the `Connection` in the narrowest possible scope, so IMO it would be better sending the `Connection con` variable as a local parameter to each method. For example:

  ```
  public List getList1(Connection con) {
      //...
  }
  ```
- Looks like you'll be executing the same query but using a different parameter to retrieve similar data. Since you're using the same connection, it would be better to have a single SQL statement that brings all the data using `JOIN`s and then group the data accordingly. Here's a example:

  ```
  String sql = "SELECT t1.col1, t1.col1, t2.col3, t2.col4 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1id";
  PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
  String col1FromT1 = null;
  EntityT1 t1;
  while (rs.next()) {
      if(!rs.getString("col1").equals(col1FromT1)) {
      //code to build the entity from T1
          t1 = new EntityT1();
          //fill t1;
      }
      col1FromT1 = rs.getString("col1");
      EntityT2 t2 = new EntityT2();
      //fill t2
      t1.addT2(t2);
  }
  ```
- Close the resources. Maybe not posted in your current code, but **never forget to call `close` method** on `ResultSet`, `PreparedStatement` and `Connection`. This can be easier if you use `try-with-resources` from Java 7.

Comment: I have used public List getList1(Connection conn){....} public List getList2(Connection conn) {....} . I believe this is what you are saying...

Comment: Aren't we introducing leaks by not closing statement objects?

Comment: yes i do have an exception block and closing connections. This is just a sample of the code snippet.

Comment: @Luiggi : No the queries are not similar. I have a huge xml structure for which I am fetching data. I have joins for a single element tag and its attributes. I have maintained the inner element tags for an xml as different java methods since its a huge xml with nested elemets. Is this approach good ?